# add variable to js from cli in webpack build

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm trying to add a variable to my app.js at the time of build. For example:

```
//app.js
var myvar = {{set_from_cli}};
```

then I want to run something like `webpack -p --myvar='abc'` which would result in this:

```
//bundle.js
var myvar = 'abc';
```

I've searched and maybe I'm just not looking in the right places or using the right terms, but can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `myvar` at **webpack.config.js** like this (assuming [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist)):

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.log(argv.myvar);
```

To get it to your bundle, you can use the `DefinePlugin`. You would need to have something like this at your plugin definition:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      MYVAR: JSON.stringify(argv.myvar)
    })
]
```

Then at code

```
var myvar = MYVAR;
```

Adjust as necessary.

Comment: Thank for the reply, I added those first two codeblocks to my webpack.config.js but now when I try to run ```webpack -c tester``` I get: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tester'

Comment: nevermind, had to add it at the right place (updated your example)